# The target entry-point "@pebula/ngrid" has missing dependencies: @angular/cdk-experimental/scrolling

Tags: angular, angular-material, dependencies, angular-grid

I tried to solve `@pebula/ngrid` dependencies error in my `angular 11` application, I import all the required packages but I don't know what the issues, If any have idea please help me solve this issues.

```
Error: The target entry-point "@pebula/ngrid" has missing dependencies:- @angular/cdk-experimental/scrolling
```

I'm used below version

```
"@angular/material": "^11.1.1",
"@pebula/ngrid": "^3.0.0",
"@pebula/ngrid-material": "^3.0.0",
```

i also tried to install

```
npm install --save @angular/cdk
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i solved this error, I asked really stupid question

I just install the below package to resolve error and it work for me

```
npm i @angular/cdk-experimental
```